# Oracle LIKE operator with DECODE

Tags: sql, database, oracle, relational-database, rdbms

I am new to learning oracle and I am having some problems in understanding the syntax.

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_BILL_PAY_LWDAY_PL
            WITH tmp_acc AS (
              SELECT ac_id,ac_currency,ac_category,ac_co_code
              FROM account
              WHERE ac_co_code LIKE decode(Currency,'','%','ALL','%',Currency) AND ac_category = '9986'
            )
```

This is the oracle pl/sql statement, could anybody please tell me what this line means.

```
WHERE ac_co_code LIKE decode(Currency,'','%','ALL','%',Currency)
```

I dont understand what decode means here with LIKE. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's producing a search pattern on the fly. The logic uses `DECODE()` to decide:

- If the value `Currency` is an empty VARCHAR ('') then use `%` as the pattern for the `LIKE`. The condition will be equivalent to:

  ```
  WHERE ac_co_code LIKE '%'
  ```
- Else, if the value `Currency` is `'ALL'` then use `%` as the pattern for the `LIKE`. The condition will be equivalent to:

  ```
  WHERE ac_co_code LIKE '%'
  ```
- Else use the value of `Currency` as the pattern for the `LIKE`. The condition will be equivalent to:

  ```
  WHERE ac_co_code LIKE Currency
  ```

See [Oracle Online Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Please note that this `DECODE` looks like clever code, but has rather poor performance. Besides, `LIKE '%'` skips rows that are `null`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This explains perfect!